# Como crear un menu vertical en joomla?

Tags: joomla3

Se que debo crear un menu en menu manager y ahi agregar los menus que quiero que contenga, tambien se debe crear un nuevo modulo de menu para que genere este y ahi poner la posicion ,todo esto ya me salio el problema es que me sale el menu desplegado yo quiero que esten escondidos los submenus y al darle click se despliegue cada uno aparte no encuentro como hacer para ponerle alguna extension que me le de diseño. En la imagen muestro como me sale se supone que el menu llamado "indice" deberia ser el menu donde le de click y me despliegue los siguientes submenus ..

Descargue la extension "je acordion menu" para darle diseño pero curiosamente ese menu no me aplica la extension si pongo la extension en el menu prncipal que es el "main menu" si me lo modifica a vertical

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no tiene mucho que ver con programación, está relacionada con una búsqueda de extensiones, la cuál puedes hacer fácilmente en el directorio de extensiones de Joomla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, lo primero, decirte que si usas actualmente un framework para 
tu plantilla, es probable que ya incluya esta funcionalidad, resta revisar las opciones que 
incluye en:

**Extensiones** > **Plantillas** > **Tu Plantilla**

Puedes hacer uso de alguna extensión como [Matic Menu](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/matic-menu) o [Ari Ext Menu](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/ari-ext-menu).

Aquí puedes encontrar el listado de extensiones de menú disponibles en el [Directorio Oficial de Extensiones](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=65&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&order=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&filter%5Bfavourites%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1).